# Criteria for moderators to take actions on push questions

Tags: discussion, moderation

The post is motivated by question [*What are the political impediments for a country in sending aid to Palestinians in Gaza, without an international consensus?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/82331/38304) In my opinion the question is subject to closure, as it clearly falls into category:

> The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician. It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes as defined in the help center.

Indeed, a part of the question is devoted to describing Israel military doctrine, followed by somewhat colorful description of Palestinian suffering, criticism of the International aid to Gaza. Then follows a paragraph actually stating the question... followed by another discussion of the exact casualty figures.

It is quite surprising that such a question remains open (and even a high network question at some point) for a month and a half. I understand that it might have been closed and reopened, since many users might be willing to promote such propaganda. This is why I think this is the case where moderators' opinions and/or action might be necessary.

Comment: The Q might be overdecorated with a laundry list of "Israeli misdeeds" but its core certainly seems valid enough:  [blockading essential goods to civilians](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/en/ihl-treaties/api-1977/article-54) is not admissible according to the laws of war.  What can countries that disagree with blocking foods and medicines to Gazan *civilians* do to "lift the blockade"?  I'd vote to reopen if it was a lot more focussed on just its title alone and I don't consider that much of a push question, merely a question in need of serious editing assistance.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica so you think that selective presentation of information is not propsganda? Or perhaps it is allowed in the case of Israel, but not in the case of... e.g., Ukraine? I think your attitude is intellectually dishonest, even though I understand how it is socially acceptable in certain places.

Comment: Meh, I think the Q is just fine, as long as it doesn't editorialize.  Which it does.  I would vote for it reopen, but not in its current condition.  Are we going to engage in a flagging-each-others-comments contest?  Because - *your attitude is intellectually dishonest* - would seem to qualify.

Comment: Related, given the history of this Q: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3894/repeatedly-closing-and-reopening-of-highly-controversial-questions

Answer (score 5):

I see mod Philipp deleted both the mega-extra context added by the OP (sfxedit) *and* the boatload of comments that sfxedit was responding to. It was probably the right decision in this context. The original Q (as it stood in early Nov) was clear enough to be answerable as it was.

I'm not entirely sure what went on in the comments--I can't see those [now], but if the OP replied to some of those there, moving the discussion to chat rather than plain deletion would perhaps been a bit better.

Comment: Yes the original Q was fine (with some minor edit here and there in tone), and no different from the many other similar Qs we get here. But I disagreed with the edit changes made by the mod and showed him the final version that would be acceptable to me and added that if he disagreed, let the Q remain closed, and leave it to the community to decide. Instead, he and the complainant, voted to delete the post. I am not surprised though - it's part of the pattern I've observed here where mods delete comments to subtly shape views while anti-western-political views can only appear sanitized here.

Comment: You can view the comments here - https://web.archive.org/web/20231201210917/https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82331/what-are-the-political-impediments-for-a-country-in-sending-aid-to-palestinians

Answer (score 1):

> Indeed, a part of the question is devoted to describing Israel military doctrine, followed by somewhat colorful description of Palestinian suffering, criticism of the International aid to Gaza. Then follows a paragraph actually stating the question... followed by another discussion of the exact casualty figures.

Since I wrote the question, I can clarify this part - if you look at the edit history of the question, the original question was brief and to the point, with some factual background on civilian deaths pertinent to the question. The comments then claimed that I am peddling false information in the Q. The question was then closed. So I had to add more info to educate the critics. Specifically, :

1. The comment, *"The Israeli war on Hamas is not revenge"* necessitated the need to clarify the Israeli military doctrine and an analysis of it in the current conflict.
2. The comment, *'Palestinian authorities in Gaza is "Hamas"'* necessitated the need to include references on the reliability of the death figures by the Gaza Health ministry and to highlight that the Health ministry wasn't actually run by Hamas.
3. The comment, *"Israel obviously has its own vested interest to ensure that Palestinians don't receive aid - Propoganda'"* - completely misses the point that I am actually citing pro-Israel arguments from this very SE on why Israel doesn't allow aid to Gaza (that Hamas will use it).
4. The comment, *'.. it doesn't mention how the Israelis were killed. If you mention the fact that Hamas had people going door to door hacking off babies head. And that 58% of Palestinians support Hamas. Then this question would no longer be biased'* - wanted me to further expand the question and include even more pointless details in the question. (Should we now add the Palestinian death and refugee figures to every Q on this war to "balance" it?).
5. The "colorful" description of Palestinian suffering is in the quotes, from the cited references, and forms the very basis of the question - the world has acknowledged that the Palestinians suffer brutally in Gaza, that all agree that killing civilian women and children are unnecessarily inhuman and tragic acts, and that the displaced refugees desperately need aid. And it is a fact that Israel denies them this for its own reasons. So the question seeks answers on international laws and how aid can be provided to them disregarding Israel's opinion on the matter.

Finally I'll add that I had originally restrained myself to only include the bare minimum facts, *all of it verifiable and defensible*, to very briefly describe Israel's questionable military tactics resulting in such high civilian death counts - just enough to provide the necessary context to the question. (If I wanted to write a propaganda piece, I could have expanded and written more about the military doctrines, quoted Israeli political statements advocating for further killing and destruction of Gaza and Palestinians, quoted even more international political opinion etc. etc. I didn't because it was unnecessary and pointless to the question.)

After I added the additional references to refute the claims in the comments, the Q was *re-opened*.

Now, after I recently updated the death figures and included some additional and latest references, this Meta post has been created to have this question closed again. (And it has been closed again).

---

> ... it wouldn't hurt to trim the question waaay down ... At the end of the day your Q is about the blockade, not about civilian Gaza deaths through bombing.

Not exactly. The question deals with a scenario where the high death and displacement (1.9 million Gazans - [90%](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPx5TUrYRF8), are now displaced and thus homeless), along with the blockade of aid, causes an *outrage* in some countries to reach a point where they feel compelled to act and they decide to do something about it (other than direct military action) - like unilaterally sending aid despite Israel's unwillingness for the same.

My Q basically asks that in such a scenario how does International Law work? Or can be used towards this goal?

So the background of the death and displacement is an integral part of the question, as it describes an outrageous humanitarian crisis, that provides the political impetus that propels countries to act despite the opposition from Israel, in the scenario I outlined. (without the outrage, a country may find it hard to get political approval from its own people, and the international community, to act).

(I base this Q from my own country's history - when the Pakistanis were committing a genocide against the Bengalis, in now Bangladesh, Indians were deluged with millions of refugees. When the supwerpowers refused to do anything about it, the political outrage in India transformed to a military invasion of Pakistan to end their persecution. But for that scenario, and for those times, it was an apt political decision. Today's times are different, and hence my Q asks about something more internationally acceptable than war. Note though that even then, as now, the west, especially the Americans choose to allow the genocide happen to protect their political interest - and that is why I included the part about American vetoing the UNSC resolution in the Q.).

The only controversial part of the question is calling Israeli action as "revenge" - I again chose that term to keep the Q brief (and because that's what [Israeli politicians are saying](https://nypost.com/2023/10/11/israeli-official-says-gaza-will-be-made-a-city-of-tents/)) instead of writing and explaining how Israeli political and military policy advocate for "collective punishment" etc. etc. That can be toned down with a less inflammatory word.

---

Note again that all the edits I made to include the extra info was in response to the aggressive comments against me and the post. (In fact, I deliberately added even more references than necessary to further irritate them, as I felt I was actually quite reasonable with my original question).

I am quite willing to remove these unnecessary info from the Q and trim it. But what about the comments? It must be obvious that if I remove the additional references but the comments stay, then we are back to where we started - a bias gets introduced that I am peddling some false information in the Q. And some other users will still react to that and downvote or vote to close the Q. Right?

Comment: Well... it wouldn't hurt to trim the question waaay down.  Something like "blockades on essential goods are illegal by rule X, Y and Z.  However, Israel, has a vested interest in isolating Hamas from supplies, so has decreed a,b,c.  What can countries concerned with civilians' welfare do to provide food, medicine and other essentials, despite I.'s objections?  The UN has said...".  At the end of the day your Q is about the *blockade*, **not** about civilian Gaza deaths through bombing.  Cutting it way down and make it less of a laundry list of "Israeli misdeeds" will make it less objectionable

Comment: https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/en/ihl-treaties/api-1977/article-54  Note that the way it is worded, food in `1.` is a separate category from "objects" in `2.`.  `3` stipulates that objects in `2` are not protected "if used by the enemy" and it specifically refers to `2` so `1`, starvation, remains no-go no matter what.